# How is a transcript with different scores reviewed?

Tags: graduate-admissions

My transcript contains a score which is listed as a percentage, and it also contains a GPA out of 10. I have mentioned the percentage score in my application for something. How will a graduate school review it for admissions in USA and Canada? By looking at the percentage or the GPA?

Answer (score 0):

US and, I assume, Canadian universities are pretty good about translating scores from different systems. If your transcript is official and you don't come from a tiny country then you probably don't need to do anything other than show what is "official". When in doubt, your university probably has a web page that provides explanations. Failing that, an official's email address might be provided.

In the US, at least, the relationship between grades and percentages can vary quite a bit and GPA is normally used, but it is usually out of 4.0 or possibly 4.5. But nothing is universal in the US, as we have no national educational system.